# Why can't I save a view properly as an image?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, screenshot

So I managed to do this for the most part. But for some reason, the image that gets screenshot doesn't get screenshot properly.

For example this image:

http://postimage.org/image/kfioellw/

Want to crop it like this:

http://postimage.org/image/kfkbxy3o/

It ends up like this:

http://postimage.org/image/kflzhalg/

This is how I'm doing it:

```
-(IBAction)cropButtonPressed {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(thumbnailScroll.frame.size);
    [thumbnailScroll.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *pThumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [delegate didFinishCroppingImage:(UIImage *)pThumbnail withSmallPicture:(UIImage *)pThumbnail andOriginalPicture:(UIImage *)pThumbnail];
}

-(void)didFinishCroppingImage:(UIImage *)croppedImage withSmallPicture:(UIImage *)smallPic andOriginalPicture:(UIImage *)original {
    normalThumbnail.image = croppedImage;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(normalThumbnail.image, nil, nil, nil);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I don't understand why it isn't screenshotting what I have in my UIScrollView. Any help? I will try to give as many details as needed.

Comment: Are you working on a Retina device/simulator? I'm not sure where, but there's seems to be something unaware of the contentscale by looking at your screenshots.

Comment: Yeah, it's for a retina device. The issue happens in both the simulator and in a real device.

Comment: You should check that the contentsScale in all your layers and images is 2.

Comment: My deepest apologies for asking this but how exactly do I do that? I can't seem to find anything with "contentScale", at least not in IB.

Comment: I never use IB, I create my views programmatically, please post the code where you display the image and I might be able to help you from there. contentsScale is a layer property, on a UIImageView is a property called contentsScaleFactor, I suspect your cropped image has that in 1 instead of 2.

Comment: i support you question did you got the idea to crop an image sergio